# An interesting puzzle in an otherwise boring game

Tags: matrices, optimization, puzzle

I recently had the displeasure of playing the Xbox 360 game Tower Bloxx Deluxe. You've played a version of it if not it itself; you build towers by dropping floors on top of the increasingly swaying tower you've already built. That's not interesting. What is interesting is the game's city building.

It gives you a grid of plots on which you build towers for people to live in and maximize your population. There are 5 tiers of tower, each taller thus more populous than the last. The trick is that a tier 2 tower needs to have a tier 1 tower adjacent to it before it can be built. A tier 3 tower needs a tier 1 tower and a tier 2 tower adjacent to it before it can be built. Eventually, a tier 5 tower needs to have all the lower tiers adjacent to it before it can be built. Higher tier towers do not satisfy requirements for the lower tiers. Once a tower is built, these restrictions no longer apply, so you can bulldoze everything around a tower and it will still stand.

Reworking this as a math puzzle, consider an n by m matrix M of 1's. Each iteration, you may replace one value in M with a counting number s if every counting number less than s is accounted for in the cells adjacent to it (The game only allows orthogonal adjacency, but allowing diagonal could be interesting too). What is the maximum sum of the values in M? What is the minimum number of iterations required to reach that value? What about expanding this to a graph instead of a matrix?

It's fairly obvious that no 5's can ever be next to each other, and that any final grid must have a 1 in it somewhere. I whipped up some Python code to brute force the problem, and it found that the optimal matrices of their sizes, up to symmetry, are
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 1 \end{vmatrix}, 
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 4 & 3 \\ 4 & 2 & 4 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 & 2 & 3 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ 4 & 1 & 5 & 4 \\ 3 & 4 & 2 & 3 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 4 & 1 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 3 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix},
\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 3 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$

Matrices of area greater than 12 cause even my fairly beefy computer to run out of memory. I'm surprised that a 5 only appears for the first time in a 4x3. The nx1's also follow a clear pattern. I'm struggling to make any headway beyond this. What can you all come up with?

If anyone else wants to use it, here's the code I wrote (meant to be fast to write, not necessarily easily readable, sorry):

```
from queue import SimpleQueue as Q


def modification(grid, row, col, val):
    return grid[:row] + (grid[row][:col] + (val,) + grid[row][col + 1:],) + grid[row + 1:]
    
    
def maximize(w, h, p):
    q = Q()
    s = set()
    q.put(tuple((0,) * w for i in range(h)))
    return _maximize(q, s, p)
    
    
def matsum(grid):
    return sum(sum(row) for row in grid)
    

def _maximize(q, s, p):
    G = ((0,),)
    r = -1
    while not q.empty():
        r = (r + 1) % p
        if r == 0:
            print("Queue length: " + str(q.qsize()) +
                  "\tSeen grids: " + str(len(s)) + " "*15, end='\r')
        g = q.get()
        s.add(g)
        if matsum(g) > matsum(G):
            G = g
        w = len(g[0])
        h = len(g)
        for x in range(w):
            for y in range(h):
                # try setting it to 0
                m = modification(g, y, x, 0)
                if m not in s:
                    q.put(m)
                for v in range(1, 5):
                    if ((x > 0 and g[y][x - 1] == v - 1)
                            or (y > 0 and g[y - 1][x] == v - 1)
                            or (x < w - 1 and g[y][x + 1] == v - 1)
                            or (y < h - 1 and g[y + 1][x] == v - 1)):
                        m = modification(g, y, x, v)
                        if m not in s:
                            s.add(m)
                            q.put(m)
                    else:
                        break
    print("Queue length: " + str(q.qsize()) +
          "\tSeen grids: " + str(len(s)) + " "*15)
    return G
    
    
 for i in range(1, 13):
    for j in range(1, i+1):
        if i*j < 13:
            print(str(i) + "x" + str(j) + ':')
            print(maximize(i, j, 5000))
```

The following code has been slightly modified to prioritize higher-sum matrices at the cost of performance. The result is that it will find high-sum matrices quickly, but for sizes larger than say 4x3, it will take a prohibitively long time to finish and output the actual highest sum matrix (though it will eventually finish).

```
import heapq


def modification(grid, row, col, val):
    return grid[:row] + (grid[row][:col] + (val,) + grid[row][col + 1:],) + grid[row + 1:]


def maximize(w, h, p):
    q = []
    s = set()
    heapq.heappush(q, (-w*h, tuple((1,) * w for i in range(h))))
    return _maximize(q, s, p)


def matsum(grid):
    return sum(sum(row) for row in grid)


def _maximize(q, s, p):
    G = ((0,),)
    sG = matsum(G)
    r = -1
    while len(q) != 0:
        r = (r + 1) % p
        if r == 0:
            print("len(q)=" + str(len(q)) +
                  " len(s)=" + str(len(s)) +
                  " G=" + str(G) + 
                  " matsum(G)=" + str(sG)+" "*10, end='\r')
        sg, g = heapq.heappop(q)
        s.add(g)
        if -sg > sG:
            sG, G = -sg, g
        w = len(g[0])
        h = len(g)
        for x in range(w):
            for y in range(h):
                # try setting it to 1
                m = modification(g, y, x, 1)
                if m not in s:
                    heapq.heappush(q, (-matsum(m), m))
                    s.add(m)
                for v in range(2, 6):
                    if ((x > 0 and g[y][x - 1] == v - 1)
                            or (y > 0 and g[y - 1][x] == v - 1)
                            or (x < w - 1 and g[y][x + 1] == v - 1)
                            or (y < h - 1 and g[y + 1][x] == v - 1)):
                        m = modification(g, y, x, v)
                        if m not in s:
                            s.add(m)
                            heapq.heappush(q, (-matsum(m), m))
                    else:
                        break
    print("len(q)=" + str(len(q)) +
                  " len(s)=" + str(len(s)) +
                  " G=" + str(G) + 
                  " matsum(G)=" + str(sG)+" "*10)
    return G


print(maximize(3, 3, 1000)) # to prove it works
#print(maximize(4, 4, 10000))
```

Comment: The paragraph starting, "Reworking this as a math puzzle" doesn't mention five anywhere, but the analysis does, so are we to assume that the game restriction on fives applies to the reworking as well?

Comment: It goes up to 5 because there are up to 4 cells orthogonally adjacent to a cell, so the restriction of 5 is implicit if only using orthogonal adjacency. Allowing diagonals would raise the implicit limit to 9.

Comment: OK, I wasn't reading carefully enough.

Comment: If you required all placements at once, it sounds like this: https://www.research.ibm.com/haifa/ponderthis/challenges/December2012.html

Comment: That puzzle is very similar, the only difference being that in that one, the requirement for the values around a cell is still enforced after the cell is modified, whereas in this one, it isn't. That should make this puzzle even more difficult than that one because it allows for the possibility that a high value cell may be reasonably replaced by a low value to satisfy other cells around it.

Comment: Can you upload the optimized solution for $4\times4$ and confirm if it is $51$?

Comment: @RobPratt The question is different here...If I were to participate I would have received 25 stars. Here is my solution for $6\times6$.
$$\begin{bmatrix}1& 3 & 2& 3& 1& 3\\
4& 5& 4& 5& 3& 2\\
3& 2& 5& 2& 5& 3\\
4& 5& 2& 5& 4& 2\\
3& 1& 5& 3& 5& 3\\
2& 3& 4& 3& 4& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

The sum is 115

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi As I said, my computer cannot brute force the solution for 4x4's. I slightly modified the code to prioritize higher sum matrices at the cost of performance, and the largest sum it found before running out of memory was, with a sum of 35: $$\begin{vmatrix}2&3&3&2\\3&4&5&3\\4&5&1&4\\2&3&3&2\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: Edit to my previous because it won't let me edit anymore: I forgot to correct the sum for how my program produces outputs. The actual sum of the matrix is the 51 you suggested.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi My modified program found this 6x6 before running out of memory, with a sum of 116:
\begin{vmatrix}1&4&2&4&3&1\\4&3&5&2&5&3\\2&5&3&5&1&4\\3&2&5&4&5&2\\4&5&2&5&2&4\\1&3&4&3&4&1\end{vmatrix}
Unfortunately storing the path to reach a given matrix would just cause it to run out of memory faster, too fast, so I don't know how it reached that.

Comment: Ack, I keep making mistakes. I think I miscopied my 4x4 there because that one's sum is actually 49. I reran it and got this one that actually does have a sum of 51:
$$\begin{vmatrix}2&3&4&1\\4&5&2&3\\3&3&5&4\\2&4&3&3\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: @Sadie I did not brute force the $4\times4$ matrix to get $51$. I purely used symmetry, such that I start from bottom left. The priority of building near the center is low. The idea came while constructing the $3\times3$ from scratch. $$\begin{bmatrix}2&4&3\\4&1&4\\3&4&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You can share your source code (for the 6*6) on [this page](https://tio.run/). It might work better.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi The link tio.run provides is too long for a comment. Instead I've updated the original post with the modified code.